# update form with database value in field

Tags: php, yii

I'm newbie.I want to create update form in yii.I created a controller Adminprofile and call the model ProfileForm.In my view 'adminprofile.php' I want to load the value for the admin from the table 'superadmin' in name and password fields.Now It displays only field without values.
I want to use update as `$update=update superadmin set username='$username',password='$password' where id='1'`

```
SiteController.php
public function actionAdminprofile()
{
    $model=new ProfileForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $name='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->name).'?=';
            $password='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->password).'?=';

            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    $this->render('adminprofile',array('model'=>$model));   

}
ProfileForm.php (MODEL)
class ProfileForm extends CFormModel
{
public $name;
public $password;

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // name, email, subject and body are required
        array('name, password', 'required'),
     );
}

}
Adminprofile.php
<div class="form">
 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'contact-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
 ),
 )); ?>
 <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Does it pass `$model->validate`? Also as side note: take a look at `Yii::app()->request->getPost('ContactForm', 'defaultValue')`, also `getQuery` and `getParam` )

Comment: Do you want to update or create ?
If you want to update then without id which row needs to be updated ?

Comment: You have created an empty Model of Profile Form.And you rendered that model in view.As it is newly created object. Field will be shown without values.Do you want a field to be pre populated with values?